# How to fix viewport width issue when using Google+ comments on responsive website?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-plus

My website is rendered perfectly fine on desktops as well as mobile devices and without any orientation related viewport issues ...until I implemented Google+ comments, which will set the width of the page to whatever width is defined here:

```
<!-- Google comments -->
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js">
</script>
<div class="g-comments"
  data-href="[URL-OF-PAGE-HERE]"
  data-width="720"
  data-first_party_property="BLOGGER"
  data-view_type="FILTERED_POSTMOD">
</div>
```

See example page [here](http://fredrikaverpil.github.io/2012/02/06/whats-jekyll/). Resize the window (horizontally) to see the issue in effect.

[image]

Is this something that could be fixed somehow, and does the issue truly lie within Google's code?

Answer (score 0):

By using `data-width="100%"` the comment box will completely disappear.